# Getting xml layout from Parent View

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-custom-view

I have a `Game` XML layout which extends a `View`, however I am not sure how I can get XML layout values within my `GameView`, please see code below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.llpartners.sanctus.GameView 
        android:id="@+id/gameview" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/vidContainerBattle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vvBeforeBattle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So what I want to do is get my `VideoView` and `RelativeLayout` within my `GameView` class. I have tried the standard `findViewById(R.id.vvBeforeBattle)`, however, as expected, this return a null pointer. Is there any way I can get this within my Gameview.class code?

UPDATE*

```
private void playVideo() 
{
    String path = "android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.test;
    Uri vid = Uri.parse(path);

    VideoView vvBeforeBattle = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vvBeforeBattle);
    vvBeforeBattle.setVideoURI(vid);
    vvBeforeBattle.start();   
}
```

Comment: Show us the code where you are accessing these objects. It also important to know from where you are accessing them.

Comment: @landl-partners see my edited answer below.

Answer (score 0):

use below code in GameView class

```
((Activity)context).findViewById(R.id.vvBeforeBattle);
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your above appraoch however still got a null pointer. I have added my java code to my questions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing your java code so I have to make a few assumptions here. But I believe the reason you are getting a null pointer is you are not setting the `contentView` layout first. Go ahead and add this to your `onCreate()` function before trying `findViewById`.

```
setContentView(R.layout.myxmllayout);
```

EDIT: My bad I understood your question wrong. if you include your `RelativeLayout` as a child of `GameView` your problem should be solved as below:

```
<com.llpartners.sanctus.GameView 
        android:id="@+id/gameview" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/vidContainerBattle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
        <VideoView
            android:id="@+id/vvBeforeBattle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</com.llpartners.sanctus.GameView>
```

Comment: This is not what the question owner is asking about, he is trying to call `findViewById` in a view subclass not in a activity

Comment: @ABFORCE you are absolutely correct, my bad. Fixed my answer to clarify.

Comment: This apprach wil not work for me as I need the VideoView to use up the entire screen on the parent view

Comment: @LandLPartners how about setting the layout_height to fill_parent as well? I can give you some suggestions to achieve that through your java code but it would be ideal if you can avoid that as it won't be clean at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of options for this job:

**1**.In your `GameView` view class get access to its parent and then get reference to your desired view

```
((View) getParent()).findViewById(...);
```

**2**.Get access to the parent `Activity` and then use its `findViewById` method, as @zohreh stated

**3**.Add a method to your `GameView` class something like `setVideoView()` and then call it in your `Activity` context and pass the proper reference to it.

As my experience in programming, the 3rd approach is better.

Comment: Hi, i tried your above appraoch however still got a null pointer. I have added my java code to my questions, thanks.

Comment: @LandLPartners You should use these methods when inflation is complete, an option would be `onWindowFocusChanged()` callback method, In constructor of your `GameView` class you can't use these methods

Comment: I worked out a fix, I have created a public static within my View and bound it in my parent class.